# Finding all URLs on a site with UTM parameters

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, url-parameters

Probably a silly question. I find myself in a situation, where I'm trying to diagnose the sources of high bounce (potentially bot) traffic to an app site that I now manage. A cursory glance though GA reveals that the major source of traffic is coming via our marketing site (ie medium = marketing site), but the source is set to "dynamic" (no manner of drilling down in GA will reveal the actual referral URL). Through poor documentation and processes, it is unknown whether URLs with these UTM parameters actually sit with URLs linking through from the marketing site or have been passed around in email comms, content marketing etc.

Having said this, assuming the main source is the marketing site:

1. Are there any tools that allow me to crawl the marketing site to reveal a list of URLs and their UTM parameters?
2. Is there a way to drill down further in GA to reveal the underlying referral URLs? (suspect that GTM has been used in the past and might have to seek out the person who manages this)

Thanks in advance,

-G

Answer (score 1):

You can use scraping tools like `Screaming Frog` that is a spider website crawler.

Once you have set the strings to find, such as the UTMs, just provide the URL of the website or a list of URLs and the tool will tell you if and where they are.